# WP8.1 DatePicker binding - value never gets updated

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, binding, datepicker

XAML code:

```
<DatePicker Date="{Binding DateTimeOffsetTest}"></DatePicker>
```

DataContext is set to App.ViewModel (static instance of ViewModel - just for a test!)

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private DateTimeOffset _dateTimeOffsetTest = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(1980, 10, 10));

        public DateTimeOffset DateTimeOffsetTest
        {
            get { return _dateTimeOffsetTest; }
            set
            {
                _dateTimeOffsetTest = value; 
                //Was OnPropertyChanged(""); (Thanks to Will for fix)
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

For a test, i simply initialized ViewModel as static instance in App.
I added this code to the button's click event handler:

```
App.ViewModel.DateTimeOffsetTest = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(1988, 09, 11));;
```

Problem is that DatePicker behaves like it's OneTime binding. If I update the property in ViewModel, DatePicker won't update. I've tried setting the mode to OneWay and change the UpdateSourceTrigger but it doesn't work.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: If everything is correct, it should work.  Everything isn't correct.  You need to add the code for the property, and an example of how you update it from code.  No doubt you've got an error in there.

Comment: Edited post with all the requested information. Thank you for your help @Will

Comment: And with that information, we have an answer!  A simple fix and you'll be on your way.

Comment: I edited the post using your fix to avoid confusion (as this was not the main problem).

Answer (score 0):

(note, this answer applies to the original code of the question)

`OnPropertyChanged("");`

Yeah, nope.  You're providing a name (a meaningless one--an empty string) to a property that doesn't exist.

`protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)`

In this case, `propertyName` will be supplied *only if you OMIT the argument in the method call.*

According to [the reference docs at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The Caller Info attributes don't make a parameter optional. Instead, they affect the default value that's passed in **when the argument is omitted**.

If you pass *any* value into the method, it will override the `CallerMemberNameAttribute`-assigned value.

In your property setters, do the following:

```
public DateTimeOffset DateTimeOffsetTest
{
    get { return _dateTimeOffsetTest; }
    set
    {
        _dateTimeOffsetTest = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged();  // LOOK HERE
    }
}
```

The framework will provide the name of the caller to the method, as you have not provided one.  Your bindings will now work.

Comment: Error on my part (I usually use MvvmLight framework), however, it still doesn't work. I tried supplying the property name too - OnPropertyChanged("DateTimeOffsetTest");

Comment: @Millkovac If that call was in your code that was a bug and this is the fix. If you aren't screwing something else up, it's guaranteed to work.  Create a prototype and see.  You probably don't have the expected DataContext on your DatePicker.  Your edit craps on my answer :/.

Comment: It works in WPF. I know that everything is set up correctly as DatePicker's value is correctly set on initial binding, however, any change does not get reflected.

Comment: Apart from the obvious bug, I don't see anything wrong.  I'd tell you to examine the binding at runtime using Snoop, but I don't think that works with the WP emulator.  If there's a similar tool for examining control state at runtime, I'd use that to look at the DataContext of the DatePicker.  Perhaps the default UpdateSourceTrigger or similar isn't what you'd expect?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, DatePicker's OneWay binding mode is bugged and changes are not reflected. You can "solve" the issue by setting the binding mode to TwoWay.

```
<DatePicker Date="{Binding DateTimeOffsetTest, Mode=TwoWay}">
```